# how to keep the Bootstrap accordion keep one open , with hashchange event , click event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, hashchange

I am trying to Twitter bootstrap using the accordion and plugin with jQuery plug-in hash change , if use location.hash open page and *click other item more times* , Before item *can't toggle close and keep one open.*

have good solution, please help thanks

**use hashchange tag** :
 #collapseOne,
 #collapseTwo,
 #collapseThree,

issue

- item open
- item open
- item close

html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span32">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">Item #1</a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">content1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">#2</a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">content2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">#3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
    $(function () {

        $(window).hashchange(function () {
            var hash = location.hash;
            var action = hash.replace('#', '');

            $('.accordion-heading a').click(function () {
                window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
                console.log('--------');
                console.log(location.pathname);
                console.log(hash);
            });

            switch (action) {
                case "collapseOne":
                    $("#collapseOne").collapse('toggle');
                    break;
                case "collapseTwo":
                    $("#collapseTwo").collapse('toggle');
                    break;
                case "collapseThree":
                    $("#collapseThree").collapse('toggle');
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            };
        });
        $(window).hashchange();
    });
```

Here's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net//komodorabbit/XyhJR/5/show/light/#collapseOne)

Here's [code](http://jsfiddle.net/komodorabbit/XyhJR/5/)

Comment: I do not know how to tell, like this state 

1.going url - url#collapseOne

2.click item - url#collapseTwo

3.keyup back - open url#collapseOne && close - url#collapseTwo && hashchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Updated Code for hash history):

```
$('.accordion-heading a').click(function(e) {
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    document.title = 'The hash is ' + (hash.replace('#', '') || 'blank') + '.';
    location.hash = hash;
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/XyhJR/8/)**

Comment: thx ,if use back , how to add listener on accordion toggle to hashchange , arrival like some history.state.

Comment: Answer and jsFiddle updated, Try `Updated Code for hash history`

Answer (score 0):

u want something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/8dMts/)

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click',function(e){
if($(this).parents('.accordion-group').children('.accordion-body').hasClass('in')){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
});
```

Comment: thx ,i try it. and with issue. and i try to arrival like some history.state. add listener on accordion toggle to hashchange